# 256 bit AES encryption in Android

Tags: java, security, android, cryptography, aes

I am using the following code to encrypt a file in an SD card in Android:

I want the code to be reviewed for:

- Security (prioritize this)
- Coding Style
- Performance

```
void encrypt() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        InvalidKeyException {
    String myString = getOutputFile();
    File myFile = new File(myString);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    File encodedfile = new File(path,"filename" + ".mp4");
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(encodedfile);
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(outputStream, cipher);
    int b;
    byte[] d = new byte[8];
    while((b = inputStream.read(d)) != -1){
        cos.write(d, 0, b);
    }
    cos.flush();
    cos.close();
    inputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: **i don't know ..... Am i using a 256 bit encryption. If not what code should i add ....** -> Not suitable for this site, perhaps for stackoverflow if it isn't a duplicate

Comment: btw Welcome to the Code Review Site, **I want the file to be encrypted in aes 256 bit.** -> not necessary, If that is the main purpose of asking the question It would not fit to the scope of this site. See the help center. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Verbosity

```
String myString = getOutputFile();
File myFile = new File(myString);
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(myFile);
```

`FileInputStream` can take `String` as argument. I'd do this instead:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(getOutputFile());
```

Whoa whoa whoa! We are reading from the output file? Did you make a mistake? I dunno, but by simply removing some lines I've suddenly exposed what could be a flaw!

### Clarity

You're making a lot of objects and doing things with them. Try putting some blank space in between. It groups statements together and makes the code more logical.

```
void encrypt() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        InvalidKeyException {
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(getOutputFile());

    File encodedfile = new File(path,"filename" + ".mp4");
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(encodedfile);

    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(outputStream, cipher);

    int b;
    byte[] d = new byte[8];
    while((b = inputStream.read(d)) != -1){
        cos.write(d, 0, b);
    }
    cos.flush();
    cos.close();
    inputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: The output file is the original file which i tried to encrypt.